# Why is jfrog-artifactory-training container always running

Tags: docker, artifactory

I followed the *Conan Essentials* training from JFrog Academy and since then, when I login on my computer (Linux), this docker container is always running.

How do I prevent this container from running automatically every time I login?
If I want it to run, I will start it manually.

Comment: Docker handles restart policy, change it according your needs https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling, I found out that one can prevent docker containers from starting automatically with this command:

`docker update --restart no` <*container_name_or_id*>